# Assigning an integer to an mxArray of pointers

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm trying to use function `mexCallMATLAB` as [described here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html).

However, I have 4 input arguments in total, so I created an `mxArray` by doing

```
mxArray *funcInputs[4];
```

And I want to assign the first three pointers with vectors (I have done so successfully). However, for the last pointer, I want to assign an integer to it, but to no avail.

This is what I have done so far:

```
funcInputs[3] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
int total = 33;
std::memcpy(funcInputs[3], &total, 1);
```

The mex function compiles successfully but the value `33` is not passed.

I'm trying to execute the function like this:

```
mxArray *outs[2];
mexCallMATLAB(2, outs, 4, funcInputs, "myFunction");
```

`mexCallMATLAB` does call the function `myFunction` as expected, but the value `33` is not passed to the function.

How did I mess this up?

Comment: The third argument of `memcpy` is the number of **bytes** to copy. For generality replace `1` there with `1*sizeof(int)`. Besides this, it looks like you're copying an int to a `mxREAL` which might not be correct. You might need to convert it to float or double before.

Comment: @buzjwa How can I convert that to a double?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in this bit of code:

```
funcInputs[3] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
int total = 33;
std::memcpy(funcInputs[3], &total, 1);
```

is create an `mxArray` object and assign its pointer to the 4th element of your pointer array, and then overwriting the first byte of the `mxArray` object with the first byte of an `int`.

An `mxArray` is an object that contains information about its size and type, and a pointer to the actual array data. You can get this pointer using [`mxGetPr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html):

```
double* ptr = mxGetPr(funcInputs[3]);
```

and you can then assign your value to the location pointed to:

```
*ptr = 33;
```

`mxPr` always returns a double. If your matrix is of a different type, you need to use a different accessor. See the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cc-mx-matrix-library.html).

Note that all the code above can be replaced by a single function call:

```
funcInputs[3] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(33);
```